# How should I sign a CSR using a signature created in HSM, in C# .NET Core?

Tags: encryption, ssl, x509, .net, hsm

I'm exhausted after looking for an answer for 3 days. I don't know if my suggested flow is wrong or my Google skills have really deteriorated.

My API needs to create a valid certificate from a CSR it received, by signing it with a private key that exists ONLY inside an HSM-like service (*Azure KeyVault*), which unfortunately doesn't offer Certificate Authority functions BUT does offer signing data with a key that exists there. My CA certificate's private key is stored in the HSM. I'm using ECDSA.

My suggested flow:

1. Client generates Key Pair + CSR and sends CSR to API
2. API creates a certificate from the CSR
3. API asks HSM to sign the CSR data and receives back a signature
4. API appends the signature to the certificate and returns a signed (and including CA in chain) certificate to the Client

[image: Flow]

I'm using C# .NET Core and would like to keep it cross-platform (as it runs in Linux containers), so I have to keep it as native as possible or using Bouncy Castle (which I'm still not sure if runs in Linux .NET Core).

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: This question should go to stackoverflow. You need help with an API or you need to be pointed at a library that does this for you (or a commercial product that does this for you). The keyvault API looks very simple to use, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/sign/sign and most of the work here is in creating the correct x509 cert to sign. Copying values from the CSR is a terrible idea, for example.

Comment: Yep, and the X.509 RFC clearly specifies which data to sign: the TBS part of the certificate (kind of easy to guess, TBS means To Be Signed). Beware of that initial tag though.

Comment: @Z.T. Asked same question in 3 different ways in SO but no one seems to know the answer.
Maarten Was wondering if there's a simple library that does that but no luck until now.

Comment: What are you most needing help with? Your step 2 (doing the bulk of CA work by making modifications to the CSR) contains a lot of steps. Step 3 is up to getting a signature from your HSM API, which is all on you. Step 4 is relatively easy given output of steps 2 and 3. Bouncy Castle does take a lot of work out of a lot of this, but it's possible to roll your own. On the Java version of the BC provider, you can implement a cert signer using an HSM API.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue and found a solution. You'll have to use the PKCS11Interop.X509Store library.
The solution uses dotnet core native System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest::Create method
for generating a certificate.

As per the docs:

> [Pkcs11Interop](https://pkcs11interop.net/) is managed library written in C# that brings the
> full power of PKCS#11 API to the .NET environment
>
> Pkcs11Interop.X509Store is managed library built on top of
> Pkcs11Interop. It's main goal is to provide easy to use PKCS#11 based
> read-only X.509 certificate store that can be easily integrated with
> standard .NET ecosystem.

Till v0.3.0, implementation for issuing a certificate (i.e signing a CSR) is not available.
With minor modifications in the PKCS11Interop library, I was able to sign the CSR.

Mentioned in [Issue #30](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/issues/30), the code is now added in the [PKCS11Interop.X509Store library version 0.4.0](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/tree/0.4.0).

The below code is taken from [test cases for BasicEcdsaCertificateRequestTest](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/blob/0.4.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store.Tests/CertificateRequestTest.cs). Test cases for RSA CertificateRequest are also there.

```
// Load PKCS#11 based store
using (var pkcs11Store = new Pkcs11X509Store(SoftHsm2Manager.LibraryPath, SoftHsm2Manager.PinProvider))
{
    // Find signing certificate (CA certificate)
    Pkcs11X509Certificate pkcs11CertOfCertificateAuthority = Helpers.GetCertificate(pkcs11Store, SoftHsm2Manager.Token1Label, SoftHsm2Manager.Token1TestUserEcdsaLabel);

    // Generate new key pair for end entity
    ECDsa ecKeyPairOfEndEntity = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);

    // Define certificate request
    CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest(
        new X500DistinguishedName("C=SK,L=Bratislava,CN=BasicEcdsaCertificateRequestTest"),
        ecKeyPairOfEndEntity,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    // Define certificate extensions
    certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, true));
    certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(certificateRequest.PublicKey, false));
    certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

    // Issue X.509 certificate for end entity
    X509Certificate2 certificateOfEndEntity = certificateRequest.Create(
        pkcs11CertOfCertificateAuthority.Info.ParsedCertificate.SubjectName,
        X509SignatureGenerator.CreateForECDsa(pkcs11CertOfCertificateAuthority.GetECDsaPrivateKey()),
        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365),
        new BigInteger(1).ToByteArray());

    // Verify signature on X.509 certificate for end entity
    Assert.IsTrue(CaCertSignedEndEntityCert(pkcs11CertOfCertificateAuthority.Info.ParsedCertificate.RawData, certificateOfEndEntity.RawData));

    // Asociate end entity certificate with its private key
    certificateOfEndEntity = certificateOfEndEntity.CopyWithPrivateKey(ecKeyPairOfEndEntity);

    // Export end entity certificate to PKCS#12 file
    string basePath = Helpers.GetBasePath();
    string pkcs12FilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "BasicEcdsaCertificateRequestTest.p12");
    File.WriteAllBytes(pkcs12FilePath, certificateOfEndEntity.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password"));
}
```

Hope this helps.